# How to generate script INSERT from result?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two databases in different SQL Server which are not connected each other.
I want to insert selected lignes from my first DB (2008) to second DB (2005).
I want to generate INSERT script, in order to execute it in DB 2005.

I found how to export all database, or all lignes in one table, but nothing about how to export only selected lignes ?

Any idea ?

Comment: is this an ongoing need or are you doing it just once?

Comment: Generate the insert statements from your SELECT

Comment: @DanielE. From now, it's just an ongoing need ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a built in feature of SQL Server:

1) In SSMS click on the source database name

3) Right Click and choose Tasks/Export Data

4) Choose Data Source and then Destination

5) In the Window Titled 'Specify Table Copy or Query' click on 'Write a query' to specify the data to transfer

6) Click Next and enter the query (it sounds like you want a where clause in the query to select specific rows)

7) Click on Next / Choose the destination and then click on Edit Mappings. You can then select Insert and the rows will be inserted into an existing table in the target.

8) You can save this as a SSIS package that you can rerun whenever you need to.

Comment: Thanks @benjamin moskovits, your steps are pretty useful :)

Comment: But as @YY Bai said my 2 DBs are not connected, so I need to use flat file destination.

Comment: And unfortunately I'm running SQLExpress, so I can't save my SSIS package :-(

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer above, except step 7). 
Since the two servers are not connected, at the step when you need to choose a destination, you will need to choose 'flat file destination' or 'microsoft excel', not the 2nd SQL 2005 DB. 
All you need to do is to export the query result to intermediate file(s), and then import the file(s) from your destination server.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just a quick note: The order of answers in the page changes, so it is not useful to refer to 'the answer above', especially if there are many answers. Refer to the poster's username instead.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that [T-SQL Flex](http://nycdotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/new-add-on-for-ssms-t-sql-flex.html) can do this for you. This takes a query set and turns it into INSERTs.

Comment: I will have a look on it, it seems to be very interesting ;-) !